# Slickgrid - get only updated/changed columns

Tags: slickgrid

I am using **Slickgrid** first time for CRUD table.

I am calling a rest service for data update from the function

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e));
```

In this function, I want to get only changed columns/data.
Right now, I am getting all of the data/columns for that row.

I am sure it is possible but I don't seem to find any method :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
item[grid.getColumns()[col].field]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't understand how `grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e));` can be converted to this answer?